# Can I connect a simple switch before or after a PoE access point?

Tags: access-point, power-over-ethernet

[image]I want to have a wired Internet connection before or after a PoE access point.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please draw a diagram and explain how power is provided to the devices.

Comment: I'm confused, the cable end saying Firewall or switch is where you would place your switch.

Comment: this switch is very far from the access point 200 meters

Comment: i want near the access point

Comment: Neither ethernet, nor PoE, is designed for 200 meters on copper cabling. You are going to need to use something else to span a distance that large. Copper cabling is designed to go 100 meters (90 meters of solid-core horizontal cabling, and a total of 10 meters of stranded patch cords). PoE was designed to be used over the copper cabling distance of 100 meters.

Comment: ok is 90 meters,can i get wired internet from tha access point?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I believe they make POE pass through switches.

Answer (score 2):

For PoE to work, the last device before the PD (powered device, in your case an access point) needs to be the PSE (power sourcing equipment, in your case the PoE "injector", also called a Midspan). Your options are a) remove the PoE injector and install a switch which supports PoE instead between the firewall and AP, or b) run a second network cable from the firewall to a new switch in parallel with the AP cabling.

Comment: To add to Stuggi's answer, there are switches that can do POE pass through, so you could look into one of those.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem: on the location of the AP you want another, wired Internet access? You can run the AP's patch cable through a switch to add ports to the network.

However, (usually) PoE doesn't pass the switch, so you'll need to connect the switch to the LAN side of the PoE injector. Then, from the switch, run another cable through the PoE injector and then to the AP as before.

Answer (score 0):

The Access point has the Ethernet port,there you can connect a PC or Switch.from that port you can get access

user will get access on the same AP IP range.